# Is there an easy way to set boolean to true if a condition is met?

Tags: java, boolean

I'm done with this assignment, but I was wondering if there was  a simpler way to achieve the same thing these code segments do?

```
public boolean noSolution ()
  {
     if (disc < 0)
        return true;
  }

public boolean equalRoots ()
  {
     if (disc = 0)
        return true;
  }
```

Comment: You'd better use `==` in second `if`

Comment: Your code won't compile as there is possibility for the methods not returning any value, and this is not allowed. This will: `return disc < 0`

Comment: noSolution: `return disc < 0;` and equalRoots: `return disc == 0;` (disc = 0 is an assignment)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you mean?

```
public boolean noSolution() {
    return disc < 0;
}
```

You can just return the result of a Boolean expression.